# Given that $1 = 27 \times 11 - 74 \times 4$, solve the following equations in modulo $74$: $ 3x - y = 1$; $2x + 3y = 0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Given that $1 = 27 \times 11 - 74 \times 4$, solve the following equations in modulo $74$:

$3x - y = 1$;

$2x + 3y = 0$.

Thank you.

Comment: I tried to cancel it down so that the equation involves only one variable and 11 or 27 so that i can cancel. But it doesn't seen to be working.

Comment: Is that a system of equations of two separate ones?

Comment: do you want to solve each equation separately or simultaneously !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mod $74$, we have 
$$27\times 11\equiv 1\iff 3\times 27\times 11\equiv 3.$$
Then, 
$$\begin{align}y\equiv 3x-1&\Rightarrow 3y\equiv 9x-3\\&\Rightarrow -2x\equiv 9x-3\\&\Rightarrow 11x\equiv 3\\&\Rightarrow 11x\equiv 3\times 27\times 11\\&\Rightarrow x\equiv 3\times 27\equiv 81\equiv \color{red}{7}\end{align}$$
Hence, $$y\equiv 3x-1\equiv 3\times 7-1\equiv \color{red}{20}.$$

Comment: @ForTeaToo: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate $y$, we can multiply the first equation by $3$, and add the second equation: we get
$$11x = 3$$

We are given that $27 \times 11 \equiv 1$ mod $74$. So to divide by $11$ mod $74$, we just multiply by $27$:
$$x \equiv 3/11 \equiv 3 \times 27 \equiv 81 \equiv 7 \text{ mod } 74$$

Now you can easily solve for $y$ mod $74$.